# How can I call an apex function from sites.com?

Tags: salesforce

I wish to use the methods of Apex classes in site.com. 
Can someone suggest if it is possible? Or if there are any workarounds ?

I have tried searching a lot but all the sites explained
how to call apex methods from apex pages which is not my requirement.My requirement is that i wish to call the apex methods from sites.com

Answer (score 1):

As per duplicate question on salesforce.stackoverflow.com - [How can I call an apex function from sites.com?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28008/how-can-i-call-an-apex-function-from-sites-com)

This question is better suited to the Salesforce StackExchange site and probably doesn't need to be duplicated here.

---

The basic [Site.com Data Services](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_overview.htm&language=en_US) allow for

> basic retrieval of data to be displayed in site.com pages and the form elements allow for simple collection of information from site visitors to be stored in Standard or Custom Objects. [Source - mark-pond](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/18587/102)

If that doesn't give you sufficient access to achieve what you want then you could expose an [Apex method via REST](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_rest.htm). The trick where will be how you get a Salesforce Session ID to authenticate your calls with. The [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US) would be a good starting point.

If you do go with Apex REST web service methods note the warning about object permissions and field-level security [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_CSH.htm#apex_rest_exposing_data.htm).